# Seeing wedding dress before chuppah

Tags: clothing, wedding

Is it consider bad luck for the chosen to see the kallah’s wedding dress prior to the chuppah?

Comment: This is very much a non-Jewish idea. In Jewish tradition there is a custom for the chosson and kallah to not see each other the week before but even this is contested.

Comment: Rav Ayreh Kaplan points out in his book on marriage that this is a non-jewish custom.

Comment: @Dov No there isn't. Both are gentile customs that some Jews do out of ignorance.

Comment: @DoubleAA that is why Isaid it is contested

Comment: @dov but you made it sound like it's different than the practice in this question

Comment: I said it as it bears some resemblance to the practise that's all

Comment: @Dov And I'm saying they are the same.

Comment: Interesting rundown here: https://outorah.org/p/5678/